# ASP.NET Core - How would I set a name with ID of HTML element on CSHTML

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How would I set a name with ID of HTML element on CSHTML?

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.Items.ItemID
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.Items.ItemModelDescription
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <input id="@item.Items.ItemID + 'UnitPrice'" class="form-control text-right" value="@item.Items.ItemUnitPrice" />
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <input id="@item.Items.ItemID + 'Quantity'" class="form-control text-right" value="@item.Quantity" oninput="return change_quantity('@item.Items.ItemID')"/>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
        @(item.Quantity * item.Items.ItemUnitPrice)
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-rounded" asp-controller="purchaseorderheader" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.Items.ItemID"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I can't get the value of HTML element using javascript is there anyway or proper way of setting an id of each quantity input? Or any keywords to search regarding this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code and description, I assume you want to calculate the cost based on the Quantity and the ItemUnitPrice. If that is the case, please refer to the following sample code, you can refer it to change your code:

ViewModel:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public decimal ItemUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimalc Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml: we could set the id attribute like this `id='Quantity_@item.ItemId'`, after rendering, the output like `Quantity_XXX`:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication6.Models.ItemViewModel>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
           ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.ItemId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.ItemDescription
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <input id="ItemUnitPrice_@item.ItemId" class="form-control text-right" type="text" value="@item.ItemUnitPrice" />
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <input id='Quantity_@item.ItemId' class="form-control text-right txtquantity" type="text" value="@item.Quantity" oninput="return change_quantity(this,@item.ItemId)"  />
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    @(item.Quantity * item.ItemUnitPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-rounded" asp-controller="purchaseorderheader" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.ItemId"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then at the end of the Index.cshtml page, add the following JavaScript: we could use the `parent()` and `closest()` method to find the current row, and then find the relates elements in this row.

```
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function change_quantity(e, itemid) {
        //find the item unit price.
        var price = $("#" + "ItemUnitPrice_" + itemid).val(); 
        //find the quantity value.
        var quantity = $("#" + "Quantity_" + itemid).val();
        //calculate the cost and change the html content.
        $(e).parent().closest("tr").find(".text-right:last").html((price * quantity).toFixed(2).toString());
    } 
</script>
}
```

The output like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help <3 this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this approach

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="tr-@item.ItemId">
            <td>
                @item.ItemId
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.ItemDescription
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input id="ItemUnitPrice_@item.ItemId" class="form-control text-right" type="text" value="@item.ItemUnitPrice" />
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <input id='Quantity_@item.ItemId' class="form-control text-right txtquantity" type="text" value="@item.Quantity" oninput="return change_quantity(this,@item.ItemId)"  />
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
                @(item.Quantity * item.ItemUnitPrice)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-rounded" asp-controller="purchaseorderheader" asp-action="Remove" asp-route-id="@item.ItemId"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
```